# Increasing resolution of 3D image in QGIS GRASS NVIZ?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, 3d, nviz

I'm trying to display 3D data in NVIZ within QGIS, but the result appears very low resolution in comparison to the same data in ArcScene.

How do I improve the quality?

I've read the question on 'How to increase the resolution of 3D image in GRASS NVIZ' - but this is based on GRASS not in QGIS and the solution didn't appear to work for my data. Both raster and elevation model have been resampled to 0.5 m resolution.

How the data looks in ArcScene:

[image: How it should look (ArcScene)]

How the data looks in NVIZ:

[image: How NVIZ looks...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about NVIZ. I would suggest, as an alternative, you look at another QGIS plugin called Qgis2threejs [https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Qgis2threejs/]. It can produce higher resolution 3D images than the examples loaded above. See these blogs:
http://anitagraser.com/2014/03/15/3d-viz-with-qgis-three-js/
http://dragons8mycat.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/create-an-awesome-3d-map-in-minutes-in-qgis/